# How to handle my vim local variable(omnifunc, ...), it is not set as i wrote in vimrc

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I use omnicomplete in VIM and my vimrc is like below.

snipping...

```
" Autocompletion
set completeopt=longest,noselect,menuone
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType py set omnifunc=python3complete#Complete
```

But, when I restart vim. omnifunc doesn't work as i set, even value is different from my vimrc settings

I thought my restoring option was problem. However, block below settings.

```
" Save and load former states
"autocmd BufWinLeave ?* mkview
"autocmd BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview
```

It still doesn't work...
How can I resolve it?
Appreciate all your help.

EDIT on 2017.11.08 > Here is my full .vimrc file

```
syntax on 
set nocp        " no compatibility with VI
set nu          " line number
set cursorline  " highlight current cursorline
set ruler       " display cursor position information at status line
set ic          " case insensitive search
set smartcase   " don't use ic when there is Capital letter
set hlsearch    " hilight search
set incsearch   " show search matches as type
set mouse=a     " enalbe cursor move with mouse
set ts=4        " size of \t character (tab stop)
set sw=4        " tab size, when use <<, >>
set sts=4       " how many spaces, when type tab (soft tab stop)
set ls=2        " last window's status line option
set expandtab smarttab
set autowrite   " Automatically :write before running commands
set autoread    " Auto read when a file is changed on disk
set autoindent
set smartindent
set cindent
set vb noeb     " visual bell instead of beep
set tm=500 ttm=0    " to leave insert mode without delay
set encoding=utf8

" Autocompletion
set completeopt=longest,noselect,menuone
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType py set omnifunc=python3complete#Complete

" Cursor shape
let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"    " Start Insert mode
let &t_EI = "\e[0 q"    " End Insert mode

" Key mapping
nnoremap <F2>    :!ctags -R -I --languages=C,C++ --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
nnoremap <F3>    :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <F4>    :TlistToggle<CR>
nnoremap <F5>    <C-w>=
nnoremap Y  y$
nnoremap n  nzz
nnoremap N  Nzz
nnoremap *  *zz
nnoremap #  #zz
inoremap <C-h>  <Left>
inoremap <C-j>  <Down>
inoremap <C-k>  <Up>
inoremap <C-l>  <Right>
inoremap <C-b>  <C-Left>
inoremap <C-f>  <C-Right>
inoremap <C-a>  <Esc>I
inoremap <C-e>  <End>
inoremap <C-@>  <C-x><C-o>
autocmd FileType c,h,cpp,hpp inoremap {<ENTER>      {}<Left><ENTER><ENTER><UP><TAB>

" Save and load former states
autocmd BufWinLeave ?* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview

" C/C++ header
function! s:header()
    let name = "__".toupper(substitute(expand("%:t"), "\\.", "_", "g"))."__"
    exe "norm! i#ifndef ". name "\n#define ". name "\n\n\n\n#endif\t//". name "\ekk"
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile *.{h,hpp} call <SID>header()

" Python header
function! s:py_init()
    exe "norm! i\n\n\ndef main():\npass\n\n\eIif __name__ == \"__main__\":\n\tmain()\n\egg"
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile *.py call <SID>py_init()


" Plugin settings using Vundle
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'taglist-plus'
Plugin 'nanotech/jellybeans.vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

" airline settings
set laststatus=2
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled=1    " turn on buffer list
let g:airline_theme='murmur'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1
let g:airline#extensions#branch#enabled=1

" NERDTree settings 
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable='+'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible='~'

" taglist settings
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window=1

" Color settings with bundle theme (type help highlight in order to see color list)
if has("gui_running")
    colo industry   " industry, torte, koehler
else
    colo slate      " slate, koehler, ron, elflord, pablo
endif
colo jellybeans
highlight linenr        ctermfg=brown ctermbg=NONE
highlight cursorlinenr  ctermfg=green ctermbg=NONE
highlight cursorline    cterm=underline
```

Comment: Show us your full `vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl I uploaded my vimrc file! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out where an option was last set via

```
:verbose set omnifunc?
```

It looks like your problem is caused by a wrong filetype in your `:autocmd`. Though Python files usually have a `*.py` extension, the filetype in Vim is named `python`. So, this should work:

```
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=python3complete#Complete
```

#### Additional critique

- I would recommend putting the settings and mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType python`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though.
- By using `:set`, the value of `'omnifunc'` will be inherited by other buffers that are opened from a Python one (e.g. via `:new`). Usually, this is not what you want. Use `:setlocal omnifunc=...` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I found that python ftplugin overwrite the omnifunc, so it is no meaning to set omnifunc in .vimrc as you told.
**vim --startuptime filename ** was helpful.

Comment: Yes, in that case, the _after directory_ will still allow to override that. Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.